# How to use Coroutine in singleton properly

Tags: android, android-studio, singleton, kotlin-coroutines

I want to create a singleton with Coroutine to load image from network. I have done implement the singleton and can load network image into imageView. Here is my singleton class.

```kotlin
class Singleton(context: Context) {

    private val TAG = "Singleton"

    private val scope =
        CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main + CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            Log.e(TAG, "Caught $exception")
        })

    private var job:Job? = null

    companion object {

        private var INSTANCE: Singleton? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun with(context: Context): Singleton {

            require(context != null) {
                "ImageLoader:with - Context should not be null."
            }

            return INSTANCE ?: Singleton(context).also {
                INSTANCE = it
                Log.d("ImageLoader", "First Init")
            }

        }
    }

    private fun onAttachStateChange(imageView: ImageView, job: Job) {
        imageView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
            }

            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
                job.cancel()
            }

        })
    }

    fun loadImage(url: String, imageView: ImageView) {
        job = scope.launch {
            try {
                updateData(URL(url), imageView)
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "work cancelled!")
            }
        }.also {
            onAttachStateChange(imageView, it)
        }
    }

    suspend fun updateData(url: URL, imageView: ImageView) = run {
        fetchImage(url)?.apply { imageView.setImageBitmap(this) }
            ?: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    }

    fun stopUpdate() {
        scope.cancel()
    }

    private suspend fun fetchImage(url: URL): Bitmap? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                val bufferedInputStream = BufferedInputStream(connection.inputStream)
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I cancel my coroutine scope in `onDestroy()` at ActivityB and than use my singleton again in ActivityA it won't do anything cause the scope have been cancel(). So is there any way to use Coroutine in singleton properly with scope.cancel() when activity is `onDestroy()`. Here is a demo:

```kotlin
class MainActivityA : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity)
        
        Singleton.with(this).updateData(url, imageView)
    }
}

class MainActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Do not need to call scope.cancel(). Cause when the view is 
        // detached it will cancel the job.
        // Singleton.with(this).stopUpdate()
    }
}
```

---

Edited
I have come up with an idea and have added into Singleton class. Using `view.onAttachStateChange` to detect whether the view is still attached to the window. If is detached then we can cancel the job. Is this a good way to doing so?

Comment: What was the reason to define a scope in the singleton if you actually need to attach tasks to the lifecycle of the caller? Why not to use the coroutine context of the caller?

Comment: Also, what is the reason this is a singleton? Do you need to have a global image cache or something? I ask because the problem would not really exist if it wouldn't be a singleton (and you would not need to use this ugly `with(Context)` approach ;-P )

Comment: The reason I use singleton is because need a global image cache. I am not pretty sure what you mean to use the coroutine context of the caller

Comment: I mean using `lifecycleScope.launch()` in the activity instead of creating a custom scope in your Singleton. But it really depends who you consider to be the "owner" of image fetching tasks. You planned to cancel the scope when activity is destroyed, so it seems to me that you really consider the activity to be the owner of these tasks. Then the question is, why to create a custom scope in the Singleton?

Comment: But while this singleton has caching, etc. it could make sense to consider it being the owner of fetching tasks. Then, its scope should not be really cancelled when the activity is being destroyed.

Comment: My concern is to make the call become more easy. Don't need to call with lifecycleScope.launch() when using it. However if not the scope is not be cancelled it would be work leak when I switch to another activity or even kill the app.

Comment: If the background task is considered to be the part of the activity lifecycle, then the activity should really explicitly attach it to its lifecycle (e.g. by using `lifecycleScope.launch()`). By using your "more easy" approach you really affect responsibilities of the activity and singleton object.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will think about how to redesign this class.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton by definition lives forever, so I'm not really sure it makes sense to cancel its scope. What if you would need to use your singleton from multiple components at the same time? They would cancel jobs of other components.

To make sure you don't leak jobs of destroyed components, you can either create a child job per component and put all tasks under it or just do not define a custom scope at all and reuse the coroutine context of the caller.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. After the discussion, I have came up an idea and updated my question. I would be grateful if you could comment on this implementation. Thank you!